# Show that there are infinitely many bijections $f:\mathbb{Z_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that there are infinitely many bijections $f:\mathbb{Z_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_+}$

Attempt: I dont really know where to start here. A little help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  do you know of one bijection?  What happens if you were to switch the mapping of $f(n)$ with $f(n+1)$ in that bijection?

Comment: Or even more simply, switch $f(1)$ and $f(n)$.

Comment: Ok I get that. However, I thought a bijection is a defined function $f$, and by infinitely many bijections they mean infinitely many functions that are bijections. So, by changing $n$ to $n+1$ only shows that $f$ holds for all elements that you put in it, does not it?

Comment: My suggestion was that we would use $f_n(x)=x,x\ne n, x\ne n+1,f_n(n)=n+1,f_n(n+1)=n$.

Comment: @abiessu Oh ok. Now, I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots and lots of ways to do this.

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_+ := \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$. For each $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we can define a bijection $\operatorname{f}_k : \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ with the property that $\operatorname{f}_k(1)=k$, $\operatorname{f}_k(k)=1$ and $\operatorname{f}_k(n)=n$ for all $n \neq 1,k$.

In words, you exchange $1$ and $k$, and leave everything else unchanged.

These are all distinct and there are as many of the $\operatorname{f}_k$ as there are $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.